# plotting ellipses onto an existing image using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I wrote a program that plots an image of voronoi cells given a set of seed points

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram

After all the colored cells have been plotted, I would like to plot an ellipse centered at the coordinates of each seed point so they can be visualized. I tried using ImageDraw.Draw to make ellipses on my image, but they're not being plotted in the right place, even when I offset the corners of the rectangular containers so that it should be centered properly. To check that they were in the wrong place, I set the seed points in my RGB array to white, so if you look closely you can see a white pixel in each color patch where the ellipse SHOULD be centered.

[image: Here is a plot with 5 seed points that you can see by the white pixels if you look closely. Two of the ellipses are centered properly around the point, but the others are not]

```
import numpy as np
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
colors = np.array([[180, 0, 0], [0, 25, 200], [10, 150, 45], [100,100,100], [24,24,24]]) #colors to be mapped to each seed point
dim = 512
points = np.array([[50, 50], [150, 350], [400, 150],[256, 256],[300,200]])
metric = 'euclidean'

def closest_point_euclidean(point):
    minimum = float('inf')
    closest_point = None
    i = None

    for index, p in enumerate(points):
        distance = round(((point[0] - p[0])**2 + (point[1] - p[1])**2)**(1/2))
        if distance < minimum:
            minimum = distance
            closest_point = p
            i = index

    return i

def closest_point_manhattan(point):
    minimum = float('inf')
    closest_point = None
    i = None

    for index, p in enumerate(points):
        distance = abs(point[0] - p[0]) + abs(point[1] - p[1])
        if distance < minimum:
            minimum = distance
            closest_point = p
            i = index

    return i

def main():
    plot = np.zeros((dim, dim, 3), 'uint8')

    for i in range(plot.shape[0]):
        for j in range(plot.shape[1]):
            if metric == 'manhattan':
                closest_point_index = closest_point_manhattan([i,j])
            elif metric == 'euclidean':
                closest_point_index = closest_point_euclidean([i,j])
            plot[i][j] = colors[closest_point_index]

    for p in points:
        plot[p[0],p[1]] = [255,255,255] # set seed points to be white

    r = 4
    img = Image.fromarray(plot)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    for p in points:
        draw.ellipse([p[0] - r, p[1] - r, p[0] + r, p[1] + r])
    img.show()
    img.save('myPlot.jpeg')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Can someone please help me understand why some of the ellipses are not in the same place? The problem is occuring in the very last for loop, but all the code is needed to run the program. To generate the image, I start with a numpy array of dimension (512, 512, 3) where the first two dimensions are the height and width of the image and the last one is the RGB component of the pixel at that point.

Comment: just a hunch but have you tried swapping x and y?

Comment: it worked. Thanks... I feel so silly XD

Comment: the documentation http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html specifies x before y, so I'm not sure why this works